# Stemming in python

Tags: python, nltk, text-analysis, stemming

I want to stem my text, which I am reading from CSV file. But after the stem-operator the text is not changed. Than I have read somewhere that I need to use POS tags in order to stem but it didn't help.

Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong? So I am reading the csv, removing punctuation, tokenizing, getting POS tags, and trying to stem but nothing is changing.

```
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer
import nltk
from nltk import pos_tag

stemmer = nltk.PorterStemmer()
data = pd.read_csv(open('data.csv'),sep=';')

translator=str.maketrans('','',string.punctuation)

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
   writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=';',
                            quotechar='^', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

   for line in data['sent']:
        line = line.translate(translator)
        tokens = word_tokenize(line)
        tokens_pos = nltk.pos_tag(tokens)
        final = [stemmer.stem(tagged_word[0]) for tagged_word in tokens_pos]
        writer.writerow(tokens_pos)
```

Examples of data for stemming:

```
The question was, what are you going to cut?
Well, again, while you were on the board of the Woods Foundation...
We've got some long-term challenges in this economy.
```

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: What is the error you are getting? How should your expected 'output.csv' look like?

Comment: @alvas there is no error, it just doesn't work in the way I expect it to work. For example, `"We've got some long-term challenges in this economy"` — this sentence I expect to see something like: `"weve got some longterm challeng in thi economi"` but I get no changes. It writes down just the sentence I have provided to the code. 

And expected output is one line is one stemmed sentence. Without row.names or column.names.

Comment: @alvas do you have any idea? :(

Comment: Yes I think I understand, have you looked at https://github.com/alvations/earthy/blob/master/FAQ.md#how-to-use-default-nltk-functions-in-earthy

Comment: @alvas oh cool! I haven't found this page. Thank you again for helping me. Post it as a solution and I will mark it

Comment: I'm glad the link helped =)

Comment: Why all this code? Your issue can be demonstrated (after necessary imports) with `print(stemmer.stem(some_word))`, where you have chosen "some word" that you are **sure** ought to be getting stemmed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have tried to debug your code. If (after necessary imports) you had just tried `print(stemmer.stem("challenges"))`, you would have seen that the stemming *does* work (the above will print "challeng"). Your problem is a small oversight: You collect the stems in `final`, but you print `tokens_pos`. So the "solution" is this:

```
writer.writerow(final)
```

Comment: Oh... really! Sorry for that stupid mistake. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should print final variable for desired output,instead you are printing tokens_pos :)

Try the following:

```
import string
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer


def preprocess(sentence):
    stemmer = nltk.PorterStemmer()
    translator=sentence.translate(string.maketrans("",""), string.punctuation)
    translator = translator.lower()
    tokens = word_tokenize(translator)
    final = [stemmer.stem(tagged_word) for tagged_word in tokens]
    return " ".join(final)

sentence = "We've got some long-term challenges in this economy."
print "Original: "+ sentence

stemmed=preprocess(sentence)
print "Processed: "+ stemmed
```

### Output:

```
Original: We've got some long-term challenges in this economy.
Processed: weve got some longterm challeng in thi economi
```

Hope it helps you!